# How to change color of hline in LaTex

Tags: latex

In a simple latex **.tex** file, how can i colorize an `hline`?

I've tried

```
\hline[color:red]
```

...and:

```
\hline{color:red}
```

...but they don't work

Similarly, how can i increase the thickness (width) of the `hline`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40666/how-to-change-line-color-in-tabular

Answer (score 10):

You need to use [`colortbl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) to colour the default `tabular` rules (horizontal or vertical):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \arrayrulecolor{red}\hline
  a \\
  \arrayrulecolor{green}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

I inserted hlines outside of the tabular environment and could simply color them by using the xcolor package and then {\color{green} \hline}.

Comment: Can you make more detailed response by showing some code or what you did step-by-step?

Comment: I'm seeing this error (although the file compiles): `Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign`. [...] `I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.`